# function round in python

Tags: python

i have some doubts in using round function correctly ,i want to know how i should use the round function correctly without any problem.
this is how how i coded in python code:
form1:

```
res = round(float(float(self.inst) - int(self.elt)),1)
```

also if put:
form2:

```
 res1 = round(2*float(self.pro),1)
```

--->it doesn't give me any result .

in form1 ,when i put integer values it gives me result but when i put float values , nothing shown .help please i want those lignes of code work normal ,  with float and integer values.

in form2 nothing shown even i put integer or float values to see if the sentence work.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. What's happening with your code now, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: What "works normal" even mean ? How to you want integer to be rounded ?

Comment: Please explain how this question is related to `odoo`.

Comment: in form1, i want to work with round operation(in a substraction operation) but it doesn't give me any result and most probably the writing of the sentence is foalt may be !

Comment: @ Welgriv , i mean if i run and make example by putting integer values it gives me result but with float values , no .

Comment: variable assignment (`var = something`) does not show any output. What do you mean by "no any result" ?

Answer (score 1):

From [`round()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) :

> Return number rounded to ndigits precision after the decimal point. If
> ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest integer to its
> input.

Rounding an integer will always return the integer you passed to it, no matter what :

```
round(42, 50)
42
```

The second parameter is used to ask for a certain number of digit after the dot for floats.

```
round(1.2)
1
```

Cause 0 digit after dot is asked.

```
round(1.2, 1)
1.2
```

Cause 1 digit after dot is asked.

```
round(1.2,2)
1.2
```

2 digits are asked, but the floating number gave in parameter has only one digit.

In your case `res1` and `res` are highly dependent of `self.inst` `self.elt` and `self.pro` so we cannot help you if you are not more specific. I suggest you write your code with one line by operation and check the results at each steps. I think your problem is not coming from the `round()` function, but the operations inside it.

By the way nobody will figure out what you try to achieve with those variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the extra float conversion.
I am getting the below result -

```
a = '14.524'
b = 7.890
res = round((float(a) - int(b)), 1)
print(res)
7.5
res1 = round(2 * float(a), 1)
print(res1)
29
```

Check for errors in your terminal window.

Comment: i make it like you say , but the problem that there is no error shown and no result shown

Comment: @diva You should write this small snippet in a new file and run that only. You might be still running your full code which is getting exited probably even before it comes to this point. Use an online IDE and paste the code above and it will work. Use print statements to ensure that you are reaching till this point.